# from django.conf import settings NOT loading dev settings

Tags: django

My settings are structured like:

```
/settings/__init__.py
/settings/base.py
/settings/dev.py
/settings/prod.py
```

The constant `RANDOM_VAR` is set in `dev.py`

When I do the following in e.g. `urls.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
print(settings.RANDOM_VAR)
```

I get

```
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'RANDOM_VAR'
```

After further testing I see that all my database settings etc. are loaded from dev.py. But when I want to access my dev.py settings through `from django.conf import settings` it doesn't work.

I don't want to use `from <your_path>.settings import dev`, because this would not work on production.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` env variable?

Comment: @schwobaseggl the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is set to `dev` and the dev Database etc. are loaded consequently.

Answer (score 0):

Your settings structure should be like this,

```
/settings/__init__.py
/settings/base.py
/settings/dev.py
/settings/prod.py
```

the you can try something like this

```
from <your_path>.settings import dev

print(dev.RANDOM_VAR)
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I don't want to use from <your_path>.settings import dev, because this would not work on production.